# Windows batch to separate files on the same folder in multiple variables

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop

I have a folder with lots of video recordings of a 4-channel dvr.

Each file has the specific camera number and the start and end frame of the recording.

I.E.: for a 2 minute recording, I have these 8 files on a folder named "videos":

```
ch1_1-1800.avi
ch2_1-1800.avi
ch3_1-1800.avi
ch4_1-1800.avi
ch1_1801-3600.avi
ch2_1801-3600.avi
ch3_1801-3600.avi
ch4_1801-3600.avi
```

I can use this command line to manually merge the files of a frame interval on a single 704x480 .avi file

```
ffmpeg -i ch1_1-1800.avi -i ch1_2-1800.avi.avi -i ch3_1-1800.avi.avi -i ch4_1-1800.avi.avi -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=704x480 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=352x240 [upperleft]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=352x240 [upperright]; [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=352x240 [lowerleft]; [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=352x240 [lowerright]; [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=352 [tmp2]; [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3]; [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=352:y=240" -b:v 2000k ch1234_1-1800.avi
```

But I'm looking for a way to proccess all the files in the "videos" folder automatically using a windows batch file. I tried a few things using a FOR loop, but I don't know if it is possible to set multiple variables on the same loop.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I tried a few things..." what things? please share! And you need to provide clear criteria that make it possible to determine which files belong together!

Comment: I have 4 channels of a same frame interval that I need to merge together
I thought the frame interval on the file names and on the ffmpeg example was an obvious tip about the file group. My bad. 
As listed on the example above, ch1-ch4 are the channels and 1-1800 and 1801-3600 are the frame intervals relative of the first and second minute of a video recording.

Answer (score 1):

Build up each set of your file dependent arguments into environment variables. Then use these accumulated variables when you call your batch file.

```
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  

    SET I_ARGS=
    SET OTHER_ARGS=

    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b *.avi') do (
        SET I_ARGS=!I_ARGS! -i %%a
        SET OTHER_ARGS=!OTHER_ARGS! blah
    )

    ffmpeg %I_ARGS% %OTHER_ARGS%
```

This shows the approach for building up the environment variables for each file (%%a) returned by 'dir /b *.avi'

Comment: I still dont get it. You set the I_ARGS variable to "auto increment" in every file found, but if I have more than 4 files, it keeps going adding "-i " to the same command line.

Comment: Can you post your updated code and the updated string that it generates

Comment: Using:
`@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  

    SET I_ARGS=
    SET OTHER_ARGS=

    FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b *.avi') do (
        SET I_ARGS=!I_ARGS! -i %%a
        SET OTHER_ARGS=!OTHER_ARGS! blah
    )

    ECHO %I_ARGS% %OTHER_ARGS%`

Gives me the output

`-i ch1_1-900.avi -i ch1_901-1800.avi -i ch2_1-900.avi -i ch2_901-1800.avi -i ch3_1-900.avi -i ch3_901-1800.avi -i ch4_1-900.avi -i ch4_901-1800.avi  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah`

And I need to separate a group of ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4 of the same frame interval and run the ffmpeg command.